# How to input a value in a text field/box by using JavasSript in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am using WebDriver with java. I want to input some text in a text field by using JavaScript. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering to input a text in Google search textfield, the following code should work:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('gbqfq').value = 'Ripon Al Wasim';");
```