# When findElement function is not able to find an text box, how to sendKeys to the text box? Is there any alternative for findElement?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When findElement function is not able to find an text box, how to sendKeys to the text box? Is there any alternative for findElement?

This is a question asked in an interview

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `JavascriptExecutor` to do the same,

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('someid').value=arguments[0]","text to be inserted in input box");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `JavascriptExecutor` in this case:

For eg. to input a text in Google search textfield, the following code should work:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('gbqfq').value = 'Ripon Al Wasim';");
```

ref url: [How to input a value in a text field/box by using JavasSript in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857586/how-to-input-a-value-in-a-text-field-box-by-using-javassript-in-selenium-webdriv)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this script:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1);         
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("element's id here"))).click();
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("element's id here"))).sendKeys("enter text you want to put in");
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we have. Using Keys we can insert text in the textbox. But before going to insert the value into the textbox we need to inspect the element which is just before the textbox and then have to press tab button to jump to the text box.

Inspected element locator value:

```
d.findElement(By.xpath("")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB,"enter your text");
```

entered text will be inserted into your text box.